# how to give space between two image buttons

Tags: blackberry

How to give space between two image buttons on the screen of BlackBerry 4.7?

Comment: This question is very vague at the moment. Can you post some code that you already have? Are you trying to do this using HTML or some widget set? What language are you using? Without a lot more details it is almost impossible to provide a good answer to this question as it stands.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - it would help a lot to show us the code behind what you've already attempted. Short questions like this, with little background info, or evidence that you've tried to solve the problem, usually get closed or downvoted into oblivion...

Answer (score 1):

you should try setMargin:

```
imageButton1.setMargin(spaceUp, spaceRight, spaceDown, spaceLeft);
```